# How can I make Java application run with more memory?

Tags: java, testing, memory, ram

I have a computer with 32 GB of RAM.

I am testing a software and I can see that it starts to work slowly when task manager says that it is using more than 6000 and something MB.

In the log file, I can see:

> name of the application, running on 8 cpu cores and 6367MB memory.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Increase-Java-Memory-in-Windows-7) and setted 24576MB but it still doing the same.

I just have the binaries (.exe files), not the code.

Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Binaries as in `.jar` files?

Comment: Be careful with that tutorial, as this will affect every single JVM you run.

Comment: no, 32 and 64 .exe files

Comment: @rmlan It is supposed to do it, but for some reason it is not affecting my program.

Comment: I would add the switches to your Java command line parameters rather than the OS.  Then it is easily transferrable to another computer.

Comment: did you log out of the system then log in again? try printing this system variable in console, does it have the numbers you want?

Comment: I am just running the exe file, how can I add the switches in there? I have tried log out and in but still same problem.

Comment: If this is a commercial application, I believe you should name it explicitly. If this is some custom-build in-house app, I think the only way is to contact the developer. If a Java app is packed into an `exe`, there is no standard way.

Comment: I thought it was possible to do it without the code, I will contact the developer now that I see that it is not the case. It is not a commercial application, is something internal for my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I don't know if it can help anyone but in my case I had to modify a .conf file on the etc folder. The developer gave me the answer.